# Joomla component include php library, not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, php

i'm trying to include a php library into my component front-end, however, when i try to declare a object, it shows error: class not found.

here is some code: (in model)

```
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/assets/php/phplibrary.php');
     $myclass = new myclass('databaseT');
     $response = $myclass->request('form data');

     return $response;
```

Please help

Comment: You misspelled file path or class name or file dosen't exist.

Comment: is the class name really "myclass"?

Comment: Not to mention,  why are you using a custom class to load form data when Joomla handles all that for you in the background?!